# Parsing/Reading a PDF Document using iText7 C#

Tags: c#, itext, itext7, pdf-reader

I'm trying to upgrade my code by using iText7 libraries.
Previously I used iTextSharp libraries
But looks like iText7 is totally new
I tried Reading a pdf Document but facing an exception in between "Pdf Header Not Found".
Here's my code

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(UploadedFileByes);

MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            BinaryReader BRreader = new BinaryReader(memory);
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();


            iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader iTextReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(memory);
            iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(memory));



            int numberofpages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
            for (int page = 1; page <= numberofpages; page++) {
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentText = iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page),strategy);
                currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(
                    Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                text.Append(currentText);
            }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you write those bytes to a file and open it with a PDF-Reader, what happens?

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution. I used the pdfreader that i defined instead of creating new one. Here's the code. Hope it would help someone.

> ```
> byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(UploadedFileByes);
>
> MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(bytes);
>             BinaryReader BRreader = new BinaryReader(memory);
>             StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
>
>
>             iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader iTextReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(memory);
>             iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(iTextReader);
>
>
>
>             int numberofpages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
>             for (int page = 1; page <= numberofpages; page++) {
>                 iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
>                 string currentText = iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page),strategy);
>                 currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(
>                     Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
>                 text.Append(currentText);
>             }
> ```